# rendering a closely fitted outfit on character goes haywire

Tags: rendering, surface-deform

I just spent the afternoon fitting a character with pants, slowly manipulating oversized jeans closer to the char-mesh:

[image]

and then parented (disabled) and then did a surface deform:

[image]

all looked good in the viewport, but the render was eye-poping, but look fine if I disable the S-D modifier:

[image]

Here is the blend file in hopes that some guru can throw a lifeline!    [image]

Comment: It's the *Subdivision Surface* modifier on *milton_mesh*. It has different levels for viewport and render. *milton_mesh* is the target for the *Surface Deform* modifier. After you press the *Bind* button the number of vertices must not change else there is a warning and crazy things can happen. Use 2 levels for viewport and 2 levels for render and you will see the problem in the viewport (*boom!*). The number of vertices of the target have changed. To fix this just press the *Unbind* button and then *Bind* button again.

Comment: @Blunder -- the best part of this site is when the expert tells you what is staring you in the face.   Many thanks !